# Hiding and showing classes with the same Class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a tool which generates a bunch of divs based on data I input into an array, however they all have the same class. The idea is that when one link is clicked it shows one of the ".catbox" divs and hides the rest.

All of these divs have the same class so I need to iterate through them, but I'm not quite sure how this is done with jQuery. Currently clicking on the last ".list" class triggers the on click event instead of all of them, and currently it shows all of the divs with the class ".catbox" instead of the corresponding one.

Here is the code:

```
var HTMLcatName = '<h1>%data%</h1>';
var HTMLcatImage = '<img id="cat" src="%data%">';
var HTMLcatCounter = '<p class="counter">Number of clicks: %data%</p>';
var HTMLcatList = '<p>%data%</p>'
var noCats = 'No cats selected m8';
var getCounterClass = document.getElementsByClassName("counter");

$(document).ready(function() {

    cats.display();
    $('.catbox').hide();

    for (u = 0; u < cats.name.length; u++) {

        formattedCatList = HTMLcatList.replace("%data%", cats.name[u]);

        var listDiv = document.createElement('div');
        listDiv.innerHTML = formattedCatList;
        listDiv.className = "list";

        $(".list").click(function() {
            $(".catbox").toggle("slow");
        });     

        $("body").prepend(listDiv);
    }
});

var update = function() {

    for (j = 0; j < getCounterClass.length; j++) {
        getCounterClass[j].innerHTML = 'Number of clicks: ' + cats.clicks[j];
    }
}

var cats = {

    "name": ["Monte", "Jib"],
    "image": ["images/monte.jpg", "images/jib.jpg"],
    "clicks": [0, 0],

    display: function () {

        for (i = 0; i < cats.image.length; i++) {

            formattedCatNames = HTMLcatName.replace("%data%", cats.name[i]);
            formattedCatImages = HTMLcatImage.replace("%data%", cats.image[i]);
            formattedCatCounter = HTMLcatCounter.replace("%data%", cats.clicks[i]);

            var catDiv = document.createElement('div');
            catDiv.className = "catbox";
            catDiv.innerHTML = formattedCatNames + formattedCatImages + formattedCatCounter;

            catDiv.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', (function(catCountUp) {
                return function() {
                    cats.clicks[catCountUp]++;
                    update();
            };
        })(i));
            document.body.appendChild(catDiv);
        }
    },
}
```

The function I need help with is found within $(document).ready(function() {

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No two elements on a page should have the same ID.

Comment: The idea is to make the elements dynamic so I don't have to hardcode each one. I'm just not sure how to implement something similar to a for loop in jQuery.

Comment: Because you're not using the ID attribute, you are better off leaving it out than introducing duplicate values.

Comment: They are classes not ID's. Updated my post title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$('.list')` you get a group of elements of class `list`, so if you use `$('.list').click();` you will bind the click event to just one element. You should use:

```
$(".list").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function() {
   $(".catbox").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the `.each()` isn't required as the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) says that it also works on lists of elements...

Answer (score 1):

The following can do it:

```
$(".list").on("click", function(){
   $(this).find(".catbox").toggle("slow");
});
```